Failed to resolve atlasmap or atlas endpoint
To import CSV data into a SQL database, I've configured the YAML DSL and its snippit below. The data mapping between CSV and database fields was defined using AtlasMap UI, and the mapping.adm mapping file was exported to the resources class directory.
steps:
  - unmarshal:
      csv:
        delimiter: ","
  - to:
      uri: atlasmap:mapping.adm
  - to:
      uri: sql:INSERT INTO log (log_date, message) VALUES (:#date,
        :#message)?dataSource=#dataSource

Included the following libraries in pom.xml file:
    Here are the dependencies:  <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc11</artifactId>
            <version>23.4.0.24.05</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>9.0.30</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-atlasmap</artifactId>
            <version>3.20.1</version> 
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-atlasmap-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.20.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

I'm seeing the following error details when it's executing:
org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route CSVToDBLoader at: >>> DoTry[[Unmarshal[org.apache.camel.model.dataformat.CsvDataFormat@656c0eae], To[atlasmap:mapping.adm], To[sql:INSERT INTO log (log_date, message) VALUES (:#date, :#message)?dataSource=#dataSource]]] <<< in route: Route(CSVToDBLoader)[From[file-watch:{{base_directory}}{{inp... because of Failed to resolve endpoint: atlasmap://mapping.adm due to: Cannot auto create component: atlasmap
        at org.apache.camel.reifier.RouteReifier.doCreateRoute(RouteReifier.java:234)
        at org.apache.camel.reifier.RouteReifier.createRoute(RouteReifier.java:85)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultModelReifierFactory.createRoute(DefaultModelReifierFactory.java:49)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startRouteDefinitions(DefaultCamelContext.java:728)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startRouteDefinitions(DefaultCamelContext.java:594)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.doInit(AbstractCamelContext.java:2391)
        at org.apache.camel.support.service.BaseService.init(BaseService.java:78)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.init(AbstractCamelContext.java:2027)
        at org.apache.camel.support.service.BaseService.start(BaseService.java:105)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.start(AbstractCamelContext.java:2046)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.start(DefaultCamelContext.java:212)
        at org.apache.camel.main.KameletMain.doStart(KameletMain.java:364)
        at org.apache.camel.support.service.BaseService.start(BaseService.java:113)
        at org.apache.camel.dsl.jbang.core.commands.Run.runKameletMain(Run.java:1299)
        at org.apache.camel.dsl.jbang.core.commands.Run.run(Run.java:844)
        at org.apache.camel.dsl.jbang.core.commands.Run.doCall(Run.java:315)
        at org.apache.camel.dsl.jbang.core.commands.CamelCommand.call(CamelCommand.java:71)
        at org.apache.camel.dsl.jbang.core.commands.CamelCommand.call(CamelCommand.java:37)
        at picocli.CommandLine.executeUserObject(CommandLine.java:2041)
        at picocli.CommandLine.access$1500(CommandLine.java:148)
        at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.executeUserObjectOfLastSubcommandWithSameParent(CommandLine.java:2461)
        at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.handle(CommandLine.java:2453)
        at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.handle(CommandLine.java:2415)
        at picocli.CommandLine$AbstractParseResultHandler.execute(CommandLine.java:2273)
        at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.execute(CommandLine.java:2417)
        at picocli.CommandLine.execute(CommandLine.java:2170)
        at org.apache.camel.dsl.jbang.core.commands.CamelJBangMain.run(CamelJBangMain.java:165)
        at org.apache.camel.dsl.jbang.core.commands.CamelJBangMain.run(CamelJBangMain.java:61)
        at main.CamelJBang.main(CamelJBang.java:36)
Caused by: org.apache.camel.ResolveEndpointFailedException: Failed to resolve endpoint: atlasmap://mapping.adm due to: Cannot auto create component: atlasmap
        at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.doGetEndpoint(AbstractCamelContext.java:831)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.getEndpoint(AbstractCamelContext.java:731)
        at org.apache.camel.support.CamelContextHelper.resolveEndpoint(CamelContextHelper.java:128)
        at org.apache.camel.reifier.SendReifier.resolveEndpoint(SendReifier.java:47)
        at org.apache.camel.reifier.SendReifier.createProcessor(SendReifier.java:37)
        at org.apache.camel.reifier.ProcessorReifier.createProcessor(ProcessorReifier.java:859)
        at org.apache.camel.reifier.ProcessorReifier.createOutputsProcessor(ProcessorReifier.java:812)
        at org.apache.camel.reifier.TryReifier.createProcessor(TryReifier.java:38)
        at org.apache.camel.reifier.ProcessorReifier.makeProcessor(ProcessorReifier.java:882)
        at org.apache.camel.reifier.ProcessorReifier.addRoutes(ProcessorReifier.java:622)
        at org.apache.camel.reifier.RouteReifier.doCreateRoute(RouteReifier.java:230)
        ... 28 more
Caused by: org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: Cannot auto create component: atlasmap
        at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.getComponent(AbstractCamelContext.java:519)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.getComponent(AbstractCamelContext.java:476)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.doGetEndpoint(AbstractCamelContext.java:789)
        ... 38 more
Caused by: org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: Cannot auto create component: atlasmap
        at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.initComponent(AbstractCamelContext.java:567)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.lambda$getComponent$0(AbstractCamelContext.java:503)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1708)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.getComponent(AbstractCamelContext.java:501)
        ... 40 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find component with name: atlasmap. Did you mean: hazelcast-map
        at org.apache.camel.main.download.DependencyDownloaderComponentResolver.resolveComponent(DependencyDownloaderComponentResolver.java:79)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.initComponent(AbstractCamelContext.java:557)
        ... 43 more


The terminal process "C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -Command jbang '-Dcamel.jbang.version=4.6.0' camel@apache/camel run pom.xml --dev --logging-level=info --local-kamelet-dir=." terminated with exit code: 1.
Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.


Also modified the uri prefix to atlas and verified it.

Included the following dependencies in pom.xml file:
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-atlasmap</artifactId>
        <version>3.20.1</version> 
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-atlasmap-starter</artifactId>
        <version>3.20.1</version> <!-- Use the latest version -->
    </dependency>



Looks like it's not finding your atlasmap component. Can you post all your dependencies from the pom.xml?

Thanks, Raphi, for your response, I've updated all dependencies in the actual post.

I've never used the yaml dsl, but in the documentation they're using a string for the route uri value. So maybe try with uri: "atlasmap:mapping.adm".
